# How can I perform a scan and plot of a parameter space?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, conditional

I have three functions dependent on three independent variables, like so:

```
H[u,m,s]
S[u,m,s]
SH[u,m,s]
```

However, I don't actually know these functions--they are solutions to three partial differential equations much like this (very simplified) example:

```
DEQ1 = u*D[H[u,m,s],u]-12*S[u,m,s]+1/4*SH[u,m,s]==0;
DEQ2 = u*D[S[u,m,s],u]-2*S[u,m,s]+6*SH[u,m,s]==0;
DEQ3 = u*D[SH[u,m,s],u]+3*S[u,m,s]+4*SH[u,m,s]==0;
```

I want to impose the following conditions:

```
H[u,m,s] > 0
0 < S[u,m,s] < 4*Pi
-4*Pi < SH[u,m,s] < 4*Pi
```

and plot the allowed parameter space that satisfies all of these conditions ('s' as a function of 'm', for a specified range of 'u'). How would I do this? I have absolutely no idea. I need to do a 'scan' of a parameter space and plot the points (the functions are such that I can only solve numerically), but I don't know how to do this. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: The ODEs as specified can be solved with `DSolve` up to three constants, which must be specified.  With this done, the resulting expressions together with the constrains in the question probably can be used to define an `ImplicitRegion`.

Comment: As I mentioned, those are overly simplified examples and the actual differential equations must be solved numerically.

Comment: Then, the equations can be solved with `ParametricNDSolve`, with the upper boundaries of the integration used as parameters, although constants of integration still must be specified. I am uncertain whether the resulting numerical functions can be used with `ImplicitRegion`.  I imagine that the total computation will be very slow.  It is difficult to say more without specifics of the PDEs.

Comment: Thank you! ParametricNDSolve worked in terms of the solution. Just trying to work around the plotting issue now. :)

Comment: Perhaps, `ContourPlot3D` or `ListContourPlot3D` to display the boundary surfaces.